# Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. Cant make Post call

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to make a post XMLHttpRequest from a host to different host.I am able to make OPTIONS and it is returning 200 code.

**Options Call Information:

Response Headers:**

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
Authorization, Accept

Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost

Cache-Control:must-revalidate, no-cache

Content-Length:0

Date:Wed, 13 Dec 2017 08:44:42 GMT

Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0

**Request Headers**

Accept:*/*

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate

Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9

Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-headers,access-control-
allow-origin,content-type

Access-Control-Request-Method:POST

Connection:keep-alive

Host:"someHostAddress"

Origin:http://localhost

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36

And I am getting this error after that and I am not able to make a post call.

My Headers :

```
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin,Content-Type,Accept");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

**Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin,Content-Type,Accept")` and `xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` from your frontend JavaScript code. Those are response headers. You don’t want to send them in requests.

Comment: Hi @sideshowbarker ,if I remove those I am getting this error   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: Yeah that’s because the server you’re making the request to doesn’t send back an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header nor any of those other headers. You don’t fix that by trying to add them to the request. That just creates a different error that obscures the real problem.

Comment: Yes, correct.I think I am missing some kind of authorization.Anyway thanks for the help.